# Android NDK irrlciht vuforia build error

Tags: android-ndk, vuforia, irrlicht

I am trying to create project which is integration of irrlchit with vuforia from here:
https://github.com/nailgun/android_irrlicht_vuforia

But I get following error when I build the code:

[image: ndk error]

Project structure is:

[image: project structure]

Android.mk is :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := irrlicht_vuforia

LS_CPP=$(subst $(1)/,,$(wildcard $(1)/*.cpp))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call LS_CPP,$(LOCAL_PATH))

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := QCAR
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := irrlicht

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

IRRLICHT_COMPILE_CONFIG_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/irrlicht
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/QCAR/Android.mk
$(call import-module,irrlicht)
```

Any suggestions about what is causing the build error would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the module irrlicht located?

Comment: you can see in project structure, in irrlicht folder

Comment: I checked the git link that you gave and there is no module named as irrlicht under jni/libs/QCAR/Android.mk.

Answer (score 1):

You need **irrlicht module** to build this project. I recommend you to ask where the module to the author of the project. By the way, at least, I got to compile it with [irrlichtandroid](https://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/irrlichtandroid) project.

1. `git clone git@github.com:nailgun/android_irrlicht_vuforia.git`
2. `git clone git://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/irrlichtandroid.git`
3. Apply [the patch](https://gist.github.com/splhack/8444711) for both
4. `cd android_irrlicht_vuforia; NDK_MODULE_PATH=.. ndk-build`
5. `android update project -p . -t android-19` (The number depends on your target Android version)
6. `ant debug install`